# Bulk split audio files in a folder

Tags: gratis, macos, mp3

I have several audio books in mp3 format and just yesterday I realise that my mp3 player cannot fast forward a track. Unfortunately, I stopped it at 53 min of 60min of the file.

My audio books are already split in files of 60 min. But I want to split them on files of 5 min.

So, I am looking for an app that will take a folder as an input with several audio files and be able to split them in bulk and keep the order of them.

Simplified example of an audio book

I have three files of 15 min each.

```
File 1, File 2, File 3
```

When I split it with the app, I want them to be:

```
File 1.1, File 1.2, File 1.3, File 2.1, File 2.2, File 2.3, File 3.1, File 3.2, File 3.3
```

But since I have a lot of audio books and most of them are already split in many files, I need something automatic. I found a few for Windows, but not for MacOS.

- OS: MacOS
- Paid: No

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280767/how-do-i-split-an-audio-file-into-multiple) unix.stackoverflow question tells you how to use FFMPEG to split audio files into fixed size chunks.

The basic command line given is for a single file but it can be adapted to work with wildcards or scripted.

FFMPEG is Free, **Gratis** & Open Source and is cross platform including **OS-X**

Comment: Since I am not familiar with command line, can you update your answer with the wild cards to apply it on all files in a folder?